# How to find or retrieve a struct model which has a foreign key and a many2many fields using gorm?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

#### Problem Summary

I'm trying to retrieve a defined struct model `UserFollowing` which has the following fields

```
type UserFollowing struct {
    ID         string  `gorm:"primary_key;not null;unique" json:"id"`
    User       User    `gorm:"foreignKey:ID;references:UserId"`
    Followings []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_relation;joinForeignKey:UserId;JoinReferences:following_id"`
}

type UserFollowers struct {
    ID        string  `gorm:"primary_id" json:"id"`
    User      User    `gorm:"foreignKey:ID"`
    Followers []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_relation;joinForeignKey:following_id;JoinReferences:UserId"`
}

type BlockedUsers struct {
    ID          string  `gorm:"primary_id" json:"id"`
    User        User    `gorm:"foreignKey:ID"`
    BlockedUser []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_relation;joinForeignKey:blocked_id;JoinReferences:UserId"`
}
```

User struct model is

```
type User struct {
    Email                 string          `gorm:"size:100;not null;unique" json:"email"`
    Password              string          `gorm:"size:60;not null" json:"password,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt             time.Time       `gorm:"default:current_timestamp()" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt             time.Time       `gorm:"default:current_timestamp()" json:"updated_at"`
    Verified              bool            `gorm:"default:false" json:"verified"`
    AToken                string          `gorm:"size:100;not null;unique" json:"accessToken"`
    RToken                string          `gorm:"size:100;not null;unique" json:"refreshToken"`
    YouAreFollowing       bool            `json:"youAreFollowing"`
    Username              string          `json:"username"`
    Online                bool            `json:"online"`
    NumFollowing          uint64          `json:"numFollowing"`
    NumFollowers          uint64          `json:"numFollowers"`
    LastOnline            time.Time       `gorm:"default:current_timestamp()" json:"lastOnline"`
    UserId                string          `gorm:"primary_key;not null;unique" json:"userid"`
    ...
}
```

I also defined a gorm pointer function

```
func (r *RepositoryUsersCRUD) Get_Following_Info(val_ref, key_ref string) (info models.UserFollowing, err error) {
    following_info := models.UserFollowing{}
    done := make(chan bool)
    go func(ch chan<- bool) {
        defer close(ch)
        // rs = r.db.Debug().Model(&following_info).Related(&following_info.User, "2")
        err = r.db.Debug().Model(&models.UserFollowing{}).Where(key_ref+" = ?", val_ref).Take(&following_info).Error
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Query failed")
            ch <- false
            return
        }
        ch <- true
    }(done)

    if channels.OK(done) {
        if err != nil {
            return following_info, err
        }

        return following_info, nil
    }
    return following_info, err
}
```

Which it is been called as follows:

```
#Tried with "id" and "user_id"   
# Also Hard coded
following_info, err := repo.Get_Following_Info(user.Username, "user_username")
fmt.Println("Test query method", following_info) #Prints and empty UserFollowing struct model
```

#### Expected Result

```
{
"id": "4",
"User": {
"email": "q4@gmail.com",
"password": "$2a$10$o8OUbFsT0nCu5iBxgC7gdeSsxxhMP4/nvRmp0H7ZGDuMgs5KQyp7y",
"created_at": "2021-12-24T15:24:56-06:00",
"updated_at": "2021-12-24T15:24:56-06:00",
...
}
"Followings": [
{"User":{...}},
{"User":{...}},
]
}
```

After checking mysql db I realized that `Followings`field has its own ``` TABLE``user_relation ```.
I don't know how to query an already created ÙserFollowing` struct from the db.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to load `Followings` with the [Preload](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Preload) function.

The code would look something like this:

```
err = r.db.Debug().Preload("Followings").Where(key_ref+" = ?", val_ref).Take(&following_info).Error
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but I get `Error 1054: Unknown column 'user_relation.user_user_id' in 'on clause'`. I also tried hard coding the `id`, but I get the same result.

Comment: This might be due to many2many relationship not being correctly defined for the `Followings` field. In the case of the error you got, it seems that gorm cannot resolve keys on its own. Here is a link with an example of how to set up all dependencies in a many2many relationship.
https://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html#Override-Foreign-Key